# What is the reason Capistrano does not have Deploy::Strategy::Update?

Tags: svn, capistrano

I use `svn update` to deploy, but have recently explored Capistrano.  I see they support checkout, export, copy, and update+copy, but not just update.  Is it frowned upon to use an svn working directory as a deployment directory and why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

one reason is b/c SVN leaves a lot of ".svn" subdirs everywhere, which can be easily exploited to get directory structure and, maybe, any file contents of your project.

Comment: Thanks for your thoughts.  I did not understand when I first asked that `cap deploy:update` creates a new, empty dir for each release (but always points a symlink named "current" to it), so it must do a checkout.  A checkout does not omit the `.svn` dirs, though.

Comment: oh, it creates a new dir each time for the case when something goes wrong with a new release and you could then easily downgrade to a previous release by pointing a 'current' symlink to it